# Flask + Wsgi + Docker - No user loader has been installed

Tags: python, docker, flask

In an attempt to run a flask project, which uses both wsgi, nginx in a docker configuration, I am facing the following error:

No user_loader has been installed for this LoginManager. Refer to https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works for more info. However, if no login is considered, the system works fine.

How could I solve this?

Some more info:

My system files are as follows:

```py
__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('instance.config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
flask_bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)


manager = Manager(app)
```

Code to control the user session:

```py
from instance.config import SECRET_KEY_LOGIN
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
login.py

from flask import render_template, request, Blueprint, url_for, redirect
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user
from app import flask_bcrypt, login_manager
from app.models.login import LoginForm
from app.models.tabelas import Usuario

sign_in = Blueprint('sign_in', __name__)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id_usuario):
  return Usuario.query.filter_by(id_usuario=id_usuario).first()

@login_manager.request_loader
def request_loader(_request):
#   print ('using request loader')
#   return "load_user_token(_request)"


@sign_in.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@sign_in.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
  if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
  else:
    error = None
    form = LoginForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
      if form.validate_on_submit():
        usuario = Usuario.query.filter_by(ds_email = form.ds_email.data).first()
        if usuario and flask_bcrypt.check_password_hash(usuario.ds_password, form.ds_password.data):
          login_user(usuario)
          return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
          error = 'Invalid Login .'
      else:
        error = 'Error'
        print(form.errors)


    return render_template('admin/login.html', form=form, error=error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your `__init__.py` this code below the login_manager instance.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.filter_by(user_id=id).first()
```

After that you can delete the `@login_manager` decorator and its respect function from login.py